# What is the role of greater <int> in set?

Tags: c++, stl, set

While declaring a set,

```
set <int, greater <int> > gquiz1;
```

why do we use `greater <int>`? What purpose does it serve?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`std::set` is a container that contains an ordered set of objects.

The ordering of the objects is determined by the second argument. By default, it is [`std::less<Key>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less). See the [definition of std::set](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) for additional details. However, you can override the default argument by using your own `Compare` type as the second argument, as you have done in your posted code.

E.g.

```
std::set<int> set1; // Use default compare class, std::less<int>
set1.insert(10);
set1.insert(5);
set1.insert(7);
```

The order of the objects in the above container will be 5, 7, and 10. The objects in the container are sorted in increasing orer.

If you use

```
std::set<int, std::greater<int>> set2;
set2.insert(10);
set2.insert(5);
set2.insert(7);
```

The order of the objects in the above container will be 10, 7, and 5.  The objects in the container are sorted in decreasing orer.

Answer (score 2):

The [declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) of `std::set` looks like this:

```
template<
    class Key,
    class Compare = std::less<Key>,
    class Allocator = std::allocator<Key>
> class set;
```

The entry goes on to say:

> `std::set` is an associative container that contains a sorted set of
>   unique objects of type Key. Sorting is done using the key comparison
>   function *Compare*.

**By default**, the key comparison is done using `std::less`, meaning that the incoming entry is inserted at the first position where it is less than the item in the set that it's being compared against.

In your example, insertion is being performed using the `std::greater` comparison, which will result in a set where the entries are sorted in an order *opposite* to the default case.

Answer (score 1):

In set , default ordering of numbers is from **low to high**.

To make it **high to low** we have to use `greater<int>.`

Answer (score 0):

As an example of using `greater` in `set`, I think of this [Monk and the Magical Candy Bags challenge](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/data-structures/trees/heapspriority-queues/practice-problems/algorithm/monk-and-the-magical-candy-bags) on hackerEarth:

> <sub>Our Monk loves candy!
> While taking a stroll in the park, he stumbled upon N Bags with candies. The i'th of these bags contains Ai candies.</sub>
>
> <sub>He picks up a bag, eats all the candies in it and drops it on the ground. But as soon as he drops the bag, the number of candies in the bag increases magically! Say the bag that used to contain X candies (before eating), now contains [X/2] candies! ,where [x] is the greatest integer less than x (Greatest Integer Function).</sub>
>
> <sub>Amazed by the magical spell, Monk can now have a lot more candies! But he has to return home in K minutes. In a single minute,Monk can consume all the candies in a single bag, regardless of the number of candies in it.
> Find the maximum number of candies that Monk can consume.</sub>

This question can be solved using a multiset and using `greater<int>`, as every time we need the maximum candy we remove that candy and need to find out the next maximum efficiently:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
#define nline "\n"
#define ll long long

int main(){
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--){
        int n,k;
        cin>>n>>k;
        multiset<ll,greater<ll>>s;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            ll a;
            cin>>a;
            s.insert(a);
        }
        ll candies=0;
        // auto it=s.begin();
        while(k>0){
            ll first=(*s.begin());
            candies+=first;
            ll p=floor(first/2);
            s.erase(s.begin());
            s.insert(p);
            k--;
        }
        cout<<candies<<endl;
    }
}
```